# Where can I find that I need this much up vote for this badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications

Where can I find that I need this much up vote for this badge?

This question is for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for; do you have a question about a specific badge, or are you asking how the upvote badges work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any upvotes in a tag, you'll appear in the top users screen.  For example I'm just grabbing at random a tag I have only a few votes in, regex.

Go to the home tag screen (from [tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), or by clicking from elsewhere): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex

At the top click the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/topusers) link:
[image: top users link]

If you're on the list, your number is there, if you're not ranked that high but have **any** votes, you'll appear at the bottom, like this:

[image: top 20 users]

You're shown at the bottom so you can still see where you stand, even if it isn't in the 20 users.  Note: this isn't real time, it's refreshed (IIRC) once or twice a day, due to the page being very expensive.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I got this long before but forgot to mention here

Answer (score 1):

[How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)

However, that query includes CW questions, which are not counted for tag badges.  The question's state matters, not whether any answers you have are CW or not; though almost all answers on CW questions tend to be CW too, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Badges` button](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) right at the top. It gives you the requirements for all badges there are but the tag specific badges. For these you need 100 upvotes on answers to questions tagged with this tag.

To know how many upvotes you lack, go to the tag info:
[image]

Comment: No SUppose I have been voted 99 times from where can i get this count ?

Comment: I am asking about badge ex:gold badge for JSF

Comment: Once you have 100 votes (e.g. when checking progress for silver and gold badges), this no longer works.  It's also wrong regarding CW status for tag badges (at least if the text is to be believed).

Comment: @org - Maybe it would be easier if you expand the question to what you are asking for.

Comment: Suppose I have been voted for 99 times but consider there is a rule that id you gets voted + 100 times you will get X badge , so how can i know for I am near to X badges and all...